# Postfix evaluator Math.pow returning a multiplied int instead of an int ^ int?

Tags: java, casting, postfix-mta

I have a problem with math.pow(). In the tests I run on this postfix calculator, I see that every time it puts a number raised to another number, it makes it multiply instead of powered. I have no idea why it is doing this, but I was hoping to see if someone understood.

I am not including any other part of the program unless you need it, because everything works fine- except for num ^ num. Could it have something to do with it being casted?

```
switch (token)
         {
            case "^": {
               result =  (int) ((Math.pow(left, right))); //Here is where
                                                            it returns a 
                                                            multiplied number instead
                                                            instead of a num ^ num
            }
            case "*": {
               result = left * right;
               break;
            }
            case "/": {
               result = left / right;
               break;
            }
            case "+": {
               result = left + right;
               break;
            } 
            case "-": {
               result = left - right;
               break;
            }
            default: {
               result = 0;
            }
         }
```

Comment: You forgot the `break;`. It's falling through to the following case.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to put `break` after `case "^": {`, so it always falls through to the next one, which is `*`.

Comment: I AM ABSOLUTE TRASH

Comment: @BrentonK Just mark the answer as correct please, if it answers the question.  Then you'll be a bit better than trash. ;-)